# How to send data from Xamarin Froms to IoTHub using Amqp protocol

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, azure-iot-hub

I have a Xamarin Forms PCL mobile App. I want to send data from my device to the **Azure IoTHub** using **Amqp Protocol**. 
But just this code is not helping because

```
deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(HostName, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(DeviceId, DeviceKey), TransportType.Amqp);
```

I tried using **Http1** but with **Http** the issue I'm facing is my app is supposed to continuously send data and recieve data from the iot hub. Like in `2 secs` intervals. So after say a certain `1 hr` maybe my iot hub reaches the throttling limit since Http is meant for infrequent calls.

And all my devices stop recieving any data.

Btw I have been using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL nuget package.

Which (I just found out) supports only Http.

**UPDATE:** We dont need Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL anymore for Xamarin PCL applications.

We can use the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client nuget package in our Xamarin PCL project. But make sure like any other PCL package you do not start adding this package to each of your platform. Just install it in your PCL project and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Btw I have been using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL nuget
>   package.
>
> Which (I just found out) supports only Http.

Yes, currently, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL [only supported HTTPS protocol](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/device#features).

For using AMQP on android(not PCL), there is a new package can help. You can check [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/26).